# How do I efficiently check if an active record object has an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an application that has tens of thousands of snapshot records.  A very small number of these 'snapshots' (say 1 in 1000) will have one or more 'positions' through a :has_many association.

How can I efficiently discover if a snapshot has a position without firing an active record query for each snapshot?  My current solution is to add a boolean field to snapshots - if a snapshot has a position, 'has_position' is set to true.  This seems a little messy since it means I have to modify the associated snapshot every time I create a position.  Is there a cleaner way to handle this scenario?

```
create_table "snapshots", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",                       
  t.datetime "updated_at",    
  t.boolean  "has_position",   
end

create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "snapshot_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  
  t.datetime "updated_at",  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will happen if you generate the migration for `positions` with the reference to `snapshots`, the migration file will be generated with a

```
add_index :positions, :snapshot_id
```

appended to the end of it.

With an index on `snapshot_id` the DB will take log(n) queries to figure out whether or not a position has at least one associated record.  Not as good as constant time with the boolean, but with mere tens of thousands of records it shouldn't take noticeably longer (unless you're doing this very, very frequently).

Additionally, a simple `has_position` boolean might be harder than you think to maintain without an index.  You can set it to `true` on creation of an associated position, but you can't set it to `false` on the deletion because there might exist another one, and you'd have to do a table scan again.

If for some reason using an index is undesirable (or you really need constant time lookup), then I'd recommend using a `:counter_cache` column.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help bdares, I am going to look into this further.  I think it speaks to a bigger structural problem that I have to query for each snapshot - will investigate this and indexes and try to resolve elegantly.